# Replace a character with new line

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

`Powershell ver 4. Windows 7`

I wanted to replace `,` with new lines in a text file. I tried the script below

```
(Get-Content C:\Test\test.txt).Replace(',','`n') | Set-Content C:\Test\testv2.txt
```

but when I see the output file I see `,` replaced with '`n' instead of new line.

I also tried double quotes instead of single.

```
Replace(',',"`n")
```

Comment: Single quotes will net you a string literal. It will not expand anything of the contents inside of the single quotes. You would want to use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText(C:\Test\test.txt) -replace ',',"`r`n" | Out-File C:\Test\testv2.txt
```

P.S. Sorry that don't have time to explain it, now.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I replaced "`n" with "`r`n"

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me.

```
(Get-Content C:\Test\Test.txt) -replace ',',"`n" | Set-Content C:\Test\Test.txt -Force
```

Comment: For anyone this is not working for the double quotes are required in the replacement.