# Memory requirement using `fread()` for large column vector

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a human-readable file containing 1 billion doubles all written in a single line (1 billion columns).

The file itself is only around 8G and I am using

`fread("filename.data", sep=" ", header=FALSE, data.table=TRUE, showProgress=TRUE)`

to load them into an R session. The script will always be "Killed" and the most amount of information I get from `showProgress` is

> *** caught segfault *** address 0x7efc7bed2010, cause 'memory not
>   mapped'

I've loaded much larger files (raw size) using the same approach in the past but probably in "matrix form" and with fewer columns. I'm guessing that data.table is needing to store 1 billion column names which is costing a lot of memory... Is this correct?

1. Is there no way to `fread` a straight into row vector (as opposed to transposing after reading)?
2. Would this data be salvageable or do I need to re-write it as a row vector?

Comment: Platform? On Linux it is rather trivial to convert line of digits separated by space(s) into one single column

Comment: Nothing in `?fread` suggests a way to read a single row as a single column. But as Severin's suggests, using shell commands to rewrite it as a row vector should be quite easy. [Here's a way to do it for Linux or OSX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169997/219475), or [here's a way with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39104275/903061) (Windows).

Comment: Damn.. I was going to suggest this but thought it would be just as costly. I'll give it a go, thanks. And yes, on Linux.

Comment: Not sure what "cost" you mean---memory, time, or something else---but it will be pretty darn cheap either way.

Comment: It sure was. Only a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fread singele row as single column?

here you go..

```
library(data.table)

#read using default separators
fread('v1,v2,v2,v3
this, is, a, test
of, fread,one,line')

#      v1    v2  v2   v3
# 1: this    is   a test
# 2:   of fread one line

#read one column per line/row
fread('v1,v2,v2,v3
this, is, a, test
      of, fread,one,line', sep = "", header = FALSE)

#                    V1
# 1:        v1,v2,v2,v3
# 2:  this, is, a, test
# 3: of, fread,one,line
```

Comment: For numeric data, the following line is useful and together with passing `sep=""` to `fread` is faster than reading long row vectors: `as.data.frame(sapply(seq(nrow(nos)), function(x) as.numeric(strsplit(data[x,], ' ')[[1]])))`